# Remove underline from Entry Control in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin-Forms and developing a login form and using Material Design (`IVisual`). I have created a custom Entry class and inherited it with `MaterialEntryRenderer` to customize it.
Thing i want to achieve is to remove underline `Entry` have. I have see alot of examples but all of them use `EntryRenderer` instead.

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
           Control.Background = null;
           Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

it work fine with `EntryRenderer` but not for `MaterialEntryRenderer`.

Comment: You could use an [Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) to do this, read the *Why Use an Effect over a Custom Renderer?* section from the link

Comment: From 2020, could try RemoveBorderEffect in Xamarin Community Toolkit.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it worked for me

```
Control.EditText.Background = null;
Control.EditText.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an effect and apply it to the control, I just wrote a detailed article on how to do that in easy steps here: [How to remove android entry underline](https://kudzaidube.medium.com/xamarin-forms-how-to-remove-android-entry-underline-4628a8d1f058)

Comment: Maybe you could copy paste some part of your article inside your answer to make your answer self explicit without following the link.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Applied to Entry, Picker and Editor too :)

Comment: Recommended, works out of the box and half a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

**You can remove it, just using [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/)**

[image: First step]

[image: How to remove]

**How it looks :]**

[image: Effect]

```
xmlns:tool="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"

<Entry.Effects>
    <tool:RemoveBorderEffect />
</Entry.Effects>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of Xamarin Forms Visual Material 4.8+, I am using the below code and it is working fine for Android and iOS.

## Xamarin Android

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryMaterialRendererAndroid), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class EntryMaterialRendererAndroid : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        public EntryMaterialRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BoxStrokeWidth = 0;
                Control.BoxStrokeWidthFocused = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Xamarin iOS

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryMaterialRendereriOS), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class EntryMaterialRendereriOS : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            EntryRemoveUnderLine();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            EntryRemoveUnderLine();
        }

        protected void EntryRemoveUnderLine()
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.Underline.Enabled = false;
                Control.Underline.DisabledColor = UIColor.Clear;
                Control.Underline.Color = UIColor.Clear;
                Control.Underline.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                // Remove underline on focus
                Control.ActiveTextInputController.UnderlineHeightActive = 0f;
                // Remove placeholder background
                Control.PlaceholderLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xamarin Form 5 version(5.0.0.2291)

you can follow this

https://kudzaidube.medium.com/xamarin-forms-how-to-remove-android-entry-underline-4628a8d1f058

just change this line

> Android.Graphics.Color entryLineColor = Android.Graphics.Color.White;

to

> Android.Graphics.Color entryLineColor = new
> Android.Graphics.Color(0,0,0,0);

in order to use transparent color

Answer (score -2):

Try  to change the Text Color property.

According to source it will change what you want:

```
_textInputLayout.BoxBackgroundColor = MaterialColors.CreateEntryFilledInputBackgroundColor(Element.BackgroundColor, Element.TextColor);
```

Look at: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Material.Android/MaterialEntryRenderer.cs